# Creation of realistic old wax

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural, photorealism

Tell me please what I must do with node of wax materials that I made. It looks very plastic and I cannot believe that this material is real.

You can see what I do in nodes. I think what dust and displacement are good but there are problems with color and subsurface scattering.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I found one sample which I'd like to make because it looks auseme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick attempt to a wax shader... not as nice as the example but there's room for improvemment. Let me know what you come up with.

1. start with Principled BSDF
2. play around SSS values
3. add dust in crevasse and other areas using AO, pointiness and normal Z value and noise
4. add some translucency

[image]